# How to install snowflake python connector on spark Glue Shell?

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

Here is the Answer:

Add below  parameters to install snowflake connector in Glue 2.0 environment spark Shell.

--additional-python-modules   cryptography==2.9.2,snowflake-connector-python==2.3.7

I have used below sample script to validate the snowflake connector is installed as expected.

## sample script

==================================

import snowflake.connector as sf

print ("********************************")
print(sf.**version**)
print ("********************************")

=================================

Answer (score 1):

Add below  parameters to install snowflake connector in Glue 2.0 environment spark Shell.

--additional-python-modules   cryptography==2.9.2,snowflake-connector-python==2.3.7

I have used below sample script to validate the snowflake connector is installed as expected.

## sample script

==================================

import snowflake.connector as sf

print ("********************************")
print(sf.**version**)
print ("********************************")

=================================